# how can I run my remote server tryton 3.6.0?

Tags: python-2.7, tryton

I want to run my remote server `tryton version 3.6.0` using the following command : `./trytond` but it show me an error :

```
~/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-3.6.0/bin $ ./trytond
/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-3.6.0/trytond/modules/__init__.py:38: UserWarning: Module trytond was already imported from /home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-3.6.0/trytond/__init__.pyc, but /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages is being added to sys.path
  import pkg_resources
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a warning the server it's running correctly, but on version 3.6 there is no output on stdin, so you don't see anything.

You can run the server with --verbose option to see the output or configure the logging as explained in http://doc.tryton.org/3.6/trytond/doc/topics/logs.html?highlight=logging